# Add snippets as own objects in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

I am developing a mail editor based in TinyMCE, in which the user should be able to insert "snippets"/"templates"/"placeholders" which should be treated as units, not text. For instance, when creating the email to participants for an event, one "template" should be **[EventName]** or **[ParticipantName]**. The user can choose where that "template" should be placed in the mail, and when sending, it will be replaced with the actual name of the event and participant.

I'm thinking about it as a sort of html element that gets inserted in the text, so it behaves just like a single character when deleting - the whole element gets deleted, not just a piece of it.

Example:

*Hello **[ParticipantName]**! Welcome to **[EventName]**, we hope you will enjoy it.*

This should NOT be able to happen when editing (part of "template" deleted):

*Hello **[ParticipantN** ! Welcome to **[EventName**], we hope you will enjoy it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at the `noneditable` plugin and create some special markers that use the noneditable plugin to make each marker act like one "character" in the editor.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/noneditable/

Here is an example: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/6ngaab

Note that the `span` tags with `contenteditable="false"` act like a single character in the editor - one cannot type within the entirety of the `span`.

You could also choose to use CSS to highlight these items some way to signify they are special markers within the content:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css

Comment: I stumbled upon this in my research, but hadn't tried it out - looks great!

Answer (score 1):

The `noneditable` plugin is probably what you're looking for here.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/noneditable/